# Is regression good for river(with dams) flow prediction

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I am trying to analyse the patterns in water flow from differnt dams on the same river at different hours of the day. I have gathered the spillway release hourly data of 11 dams for 2013. I know that I have to consider rainfall index too but I'm starting with just water release data. Is multiple regression a good way to predict these flows for the next day's hourly flow?

Comment: What variables would you include in your multiple regression model?  What would the output of your analysis be?

Comment: the flow information of spillway releases in cubic ft per sec generated at different dam locations. 
So column 1 is dam1 spillway release, 
   column 2 is dam2 spillway release,....

Comment: the output of the analysis will be hourly prediction of next day's flow. I want to train the model with 2013 year's data and compare it with 2014 year's data

Comment: Default models favored by many--including multiple regression and standard time series analysis procedures--are unlikely to be much help, because the dam flows depend not only on hydrological parameters--recent rainfall, local cover, soil saturation, and more--but they also depend on how those dams are being controlled. You might accomplish much more with much less effort by looking into the procedures used to control the dam releases.

Comment: Great! also the water flowing into the rivers through other creeks should influence the flows. Also when I get the procedures used to control I can make a decision tree and predict probably. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Regression requires certain assumptions regarding independence in the error term which is free of pulses/level shifts/seasonal pulses/local time trends and non-constancy of the error variance. Since you have time series data certain complications/opportunities may arise. I once wrote an article entitled Regression vs. Box-Jenkins to help explain this and it may help you understand the issues involved.  http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/afs-university/intro-to-forecasting/doc_download/24-regression-vs-box-jenkins  , Your daily data possibly influenced by your predictor may well include lags structures, temporal effects and possible level/trend effects.  The methodology that you should be considering is called Transfer Functions . An example of this methodology to water levels is here http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/news/166-051393-used-in-us-department-of-the-interior-technical-report-prediction-of-water-use-in-puerto-ricoqby-nazario-d-ramirez-beltran.

Comment: @Nick Cox .... what happened to your positive comment

Comment: It was deleted! I don't think I understand the OP's problem. But impute positive comment on your answer. Clearly, the OP must think about dependence in time as well as other elements.

Comment: who is OP by the way?

Comment: *You* are the "OP": original proposer/poster/poser of the question.